# How to access a dict's values and delete them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a Python dict `stuffs` with keys and values(list);

```
{'car':['bmw','porsche','benz'] 'fruits':['banana','apple']}
```

And I would like delete first value from cars: `bmw` and first value from fruits: `banana`

How can I access and delete them please? I have tried `.pop(index)`, but it doesn't work...

Comment: What did you call `pop` on?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @wbadart stuffs.pop(1), but it wont access that list

Comment: `del stuffs['car'][0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way of doing this is to use a for loop and iterate over each item in you're dictionary, and pop the first element:

```
dictionary = {'car':['bmw','porsche','benz'], 'fruits':['banana','apple']}
for key in dictionary:
    dictionary[key].pop(0)
```

<s>Or, as a list comprehension</s>

```
dictionary = {'car':['bmw','porsche','benz'], 'fruits':['banana','apple']}
[dictionary[i].pop(0) for i in dictionary]
```

These pieces of code reference the dictionary at each of it's keys (`'car'` and `'fruits'`) and then proceeds to use `pop` on the values indexed by these keys.

Edit:

Don't use a list comprehension if you don't intend to store the list. In the case where you are iterating over large values, you could run into memory errors due to storing a whole load of useless values. Such as in this case:

`[print(i) for i in range(9823498)]`

This will store 9823498 `None` values*, where as a for loop would not. but still achieve the same thing.

Comment: Do not use list-comprehensions for side-effects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what do you mean side-effects?

Comment: You are building a useless list with that list comprehension. This is not good practice at all; list comprehensions are not substitutes for `for` loops.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Just to be clear so anyone who sees this understands why it is bad practice, can you elaborate?

Comment: Read the link Timothy32 provided. In addition, list comprehensions are functional programming constructs, they signal "this is a mapping/filtering operation", people don't expect side effects for that. If you want to write imperative code, then use the imperative constructs

Comment: "This will store all the values from 0 -> 9823498" no, it won't. It create a list of all `None` objects with a length of `9823498`. `print` to s a function purely for a side effect, printing to stdout. It returns `None`

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new dictionary where you skip the first element using `[1:]`

```
stuffs = {'car':['bmw','porsche','benz'], 'fruits':['banana','apple']}
stuffs_new = {k:v[1:] for k,v in stuffs.items()}
# {'car': ['porsche', 'benz'], 'fruits': ['apple']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.

Use either:

```
del dict[key]
```

Or

```
dict.pop(key, value)
```

The second will remove but also leave the item available as a return

Comment: This will delete an entire key, he only wants the first index of the value indexed by the key to be removed

Comment: @Recessive You are totally right, misinterpreted it. Even still, just the syntax of pop would be helpful for him I guess, considering it takes different arguments from what he had tried.